# Standard library partition algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I wrote this partition function:

```
template <class I, class P> I partition(I beg, I end, P p)
{
    I first = beg;
    while(beg != end) {
        if(!p(*beg))
            beg++;
        else {
            // if(beg != first) - EDIT: add conditional to prevent swapping identical elements
            std::swap(*beg, *first);
            first++;
            beg++;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

I've tested it with a few outputs and I haven't found anything wrong with it.

The standard library partition function is equivalent to:

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
  BidirectionalIterator partition (BidirectionalIterator first,
                                   BidirectionalIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    while (pred(*first)) {
      ++first;
      if (first==last) return first;
    }
    do {
      --last;
      if (first==last) return first;
    } while (!pred(*last));
    swap (*first,*last);
    ++first;
  }
  return first;
}
```

The latter seems much more complicated and has nested loops. Is there something wrong with my version? If not why the more complicated version?

Here is some output using the following predicate:

```
bool greaterthantwo(double val)
{
    return val > 2;
}
```

`MAIN`

```
std::vector<double> test{1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,4,8,2,4,10};
std::vector<double>::iterator part = ::partition(test.begin(), test.end(), greaterthantwo);
for(const auto &ref:test)
    std::cout << ref << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
for(auto it = part; it != test.end(); it++)
    std::cout << *it << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

`OUTPUT`

```
3 4 5 6 7 4 8 4 10 2 2 2 1 
2 2 2 1
```

Comment: the STL function is "Optimized".

Comment: You are using postfix ++ and --, while the STL is using prefix ++ and --. If you had a particularly substantial iterator, the postfix form may be slower, because it returns a value (a copy of the pre-modification iterator) instead of a reference. Prefer the prefix form if you don't need the postfix semantics.

Comment: just curious, which STL library implemented 'partition' in this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your version is close to Nico Lomuto `partition`. Such `partition` works on `ForwardIterator`s and is semi-[stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) (first part is stable, which can be useful in some circumstances).

Version from implementation of standard library which you quoted is close to `partition` described by [C. A. R. Hoare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare) at his paper "Quicksort". It works on `BidirectionalIterator`s, and does not imply any stability.

Let's compare them on following case:

```
FTTTT
```

Forward `partition` will proceed like this:

```
FTTTT
TFTTT
TTFTT
TTTFT
TTTTF
```

resulting in `swap` on each iteration except first, while Bidirectional partition will go thru following permutations:

```
FTTTT
TTTTF
```

resulting only in one `swap` for all iterations.

Moreover, in general case Bidirectional will do N/2 `swap`s at maximum, while Forward version can do up to ~N `swap`s.

`std::partition` in C++98/03 works on `BidirectionalIterator`s, but in C++11 they relaxed requirements to `ForwardIterator`s (though, it doesn't have to be semi-stable). Complexity requirements:

> Complexity: If `ForwardIterator` meets the requirements for a `BidirectionalIterator`, at most (`last` -`first`) / 2 swaps are done; otherwise at most `last` - `first` swaps are done. Exactly last - first applications of the predicate are done.

As you can see, implementations of standard library most likely will use Lomuto's `partition` for `ForwardIterator`s and Hoare's `partition` for `BidirectionalIterator`s.

[Alexander Stepanov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov) discuses `partition` problem in his [Notes on Programming](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf) and in [Elements of Programming](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/) co-authored with [Paul McJones](http://www.mcjones.org/paul/)

---

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0946712d9cf0a1a6)

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <forward_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;

struct T
{
    int value;
    T(int x = 0) : value(x) {}
    T(const T &x)
    {
        ++counter;
        value = x.value;
    }
    T &operator=(const T &x)
    {
        ++counter;
        value = x.value;
        return *this;
    }
};
auto pred = [](const T &x){return x.value;};

template<typename Container>
void test()
{
    Container l = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    counter = 0;
    partition(begin(l), end(l), pred);
    cout << "Moves count: " << counter << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test<forward_list<T>>();
    test<list<T>>();
}
```

Output is:

```
Moves count: 12
Moves count: 3
```

(`swap` is 3 `move`s)

Answer (score 3):

Your function has a serious defect. It swaps each element that satisfies the predicate with itself if initial elements of the sequence satisfy the predicate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should put an if statement testing if `beg` and `first` are equal.

Comment: In fact in this case you will include code from the stl realization while (pred(*first)) { ++first; if (first==last) return first; }

Comment: @Dochevsky This check makes sense only for the corner case which Vlad mentioned in the answer. For other cases it's just a waste of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

From [STL partition description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/)

Complexity
Linear in the distance between first and last: Applies pred to each element, and possibly swaps some of them (if the iterator type is a bidirectional, at most half that many swaps, otherwise at most that many).

In your implementation you swap more.

Comment: Does my implementation end up swapping more even with the correction where I prevent swapping of identical elements? If I did `if(beg != first)` before the swap.

Comment: In fact in this case you will include code from the stl realization     while (pred(*first)) {
      ++first;
      if (first==last) return first;
    }